# Errors in eclipse pom.xml but maven clean install is successful

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

It seems that the property `${user.dir}` is recognized by Maven but not recognized by Eclipse. I am seeing the errors below in the pom.xml file in eclipse everywhere then there is a reference to this section:

```
<outputDirectory>${user.dir}\Nightly_Build\lib</outputDirectory>
```

The errors are:

```
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath.segmentCount()" because "outputDir" is null (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar:bpcstudioToats:package)

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath.segmentCount()" because "outputDir" is null
```

The good thing is that the command `mvn clean install` is working fine. I run this command from eclipse right-click run/build and from the command line, and all is working fine.

This is causing eclipse not to recognize the maven dependencies correctly, and reporting compilation errors in various places, and the compilation in maven is successful.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

## Update:

I replaced all references to `user.dir` with `project.basedir` in all pom.xml, did a project clean, and updated maven, then all errors disappeared. But, I could see a new folder was created under each project base directory. I will check what was the intent of using `user.dir` and then will provide an update.

Comment: Using `${user.dir}` in a `pom.xml` is an anti-pattern that should be avoided. If you want to do it anyway, try to [specify `<user.dir>...</user.dir>` in the `settings.xml` file](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#properties) that is configured in the preferences _Maven > User Settings_ and which might need to be created first.

Comment: The result of generated artifacts (like jar etc.) is the `target` directory... If you like to put those files in your local cache (aka local repository) you can use `mvn install`... Configuring output directory in a different way makes no sense (also as mentioned anti-pattern!)

Comment: I understand your point about anti-pattern... But it is how it is, for now, it's hard to change it. Let me see what I can do. I have to do some research first. Note that even vscode is not complaining about that.

Comment: @howlger I replaced `user.dir` with `project.basedir` in all the pom.xml files and all errors disappeared, and the maven update worked without any problem. I think the only problem now is the intended output directly is different. I think the intended output is the base root of the parent pom.xml (reactor) file. How do I get the path of the parent pom.xml reactor file?

Comment: If a relative path (like e.g. `${project.basedir}/..`) does not work, please explain with a minimal reproducible example what you want to do.