Convert Imported Maven Sub Module to a Maven Project in Eclipse
I have a multi-module maven project which I imported to Eclipse. I did struggle initially to import it with all its sub-modules but per what I remember, the sub-modules were not converted to Maven Project in Eclipse and they didn't even look like a Java Project. I remember that I used the option "Configure and detect nested projects" and did another import for Existing Maven Project for each sub-module and things looked fine. Even the Maven Build from Eclipse was successful.
However, today I noticed that the node "Maven Dependencies" doesn't show under the sub-module node in Eclipse, and I don't see the maven dependencies. I could only see the "JRE System Library" node. I compared the configuration to another project that was imported successfully as Maven Project, and figured out that this newly imported project in Eclipse, its sub-modules are not recognized as Maven Project.
Then, I used the command mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse and now I can see the Maven Dependencies showing as "Library Dependencies" which means it is still a Java Project not a Maven Project.
I am trying to locate the option to convert it to a Maven project, but I don't see such an option.
I am thinking to backup one of the sub-modules, delete it from Eclipse and re-import it as a Maven Project.
Any idea how to resolve this problem, please let me know.

Update 1:
Below is the .project file of the project that was imported successfully:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>proj_name</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>

Below is the .calsspath file of the project that was imported successfuly:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry excluding="path/to/some/file/being/excluded/coming/from/pom/xml/_ServerMessagesTest.java" kind="src" output="Nightly_Build/proj_name" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="Nightly_Build/proj_name" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="Nightly_Build/proj_name"/>
</classpath>

Notes/questions:

The project that was imported successfully is the same as the project that was not imported successfully, but the latter is a newer version. So, to import the 2nd project, I had to use the option Import->Existing Maven Project->Advanced->Name template and I specified a template to change the project name by adding a version suffix to the project name.
I also used Configure->Configure and detect nested projects but I don't remember what I did exactly.
By comparing the above files with those of the project that was not imported successfully, I can guess what needs to be changed but I want to do the change using Eclipse options.
Is there an option in Eclipse to undo the changes made to convert the project to Maven and redo the change to ensure it becomes a proper Maven Project?


Do not use mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse. A long time ago when Maven was new, this was the way to add dependencies in Eclipse without Maven support (with the disadvantage that it has to be run on each dependency change). Please show your  .classpath and .project files or restore those files yourself by comparing them with the ones from the project that was imported successfully.

You want me to add the .project and .classpath of the project that was imported successfully, correct?

@howlger please see the update made to this question.

The added .project file containing org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder builder and org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature nature looks fine. In the .classpath the maven.pomderived entries look also fine, but output="Nightly_Build/proj_name" instead of output="target/classes" looks unusual. In the non-functioning project, it is probably different, which would explain the issue.

@howlger output parameter you mentioned matches that of the project imported successfully. I guess the problem is that the project is muti-module Maven and checkout from SVN is causing this problem. I'm thinking to delete the project from the workspace, delete the classpath and project files from all the folders, and reimport the entire project back. Are you aware of a sample muti-module Maven project from GitHub I can experiment with?

@howlger I remembered I already raised the same issue here https://stackoverflow.com/q/75381221/4180447 it's exactly the same symptoms. Same compile errors and the Maven Dependencies are not showing causing package resolution compilation errors in eclipse because the JAR files specified in pom.xml are not registered as a dependency.
